# Can we define a Monad instance for WrappedArrow?

Tags: haskell, monads, arrows

[`WrappedArrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:WrappedArrow) is an instance of `Applicative`, but can it be made a `Monad` (probably if the arrow is `ArrowApply`)?

```
instance ArrowApply a => Monad (WrappedArrow a b) where
  return = pure
  (>>) = (*>)
  (>>=) = ???
```

EDIT:

My initial purpose was to have a Monad instance for (wrapped) Kleisli, so I could write

```
runWithInput input $ do
  action1
  action2
  action3
  ...
```

instead of

```
do
  output1 <- action1 input
  output2 <- action2 output1
  output3 <- action3 output2
  ...
```

But I realized that won't make desirable sense. Stripped of newtypes, `Kleisli f a b >> Kleisli f a c` is

```
(a -> f b) -> (a -> f c) -> (a -> f c)
```

And what I need is analog of `>>>`, i.e. **b** instead of second `a`:

```
(a -> f b) -> (b -> f c) -> (a -> f c)
```

So I suppose I will have to use `StateT` or a custom monad if I want to sequence actions in this manner with `do`.

Comment: Maybe you want [`Control.Arrow.ArrowMonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowMonad) ? When `b` is not `()` I guess it's trickier to define a sensible monad instance.

Comment: In order to define such an instance, you would additionally need a function `swap :: forall x y z . arr x (arr y z) -> arr y (arr x z)` ; then `>>= = \x f -> swap (arr f) &&& x >>> app`. It is fairly easy to define such a function for the `Arrow` instances in `base`, but I can't say how useful it is in general.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you probably already know that, but in any case it is worth mentioning that you might write `action1 >=> action2 >=> action3` instead (`(>=>)` is literally `(>>>)` for Kleisli arrows).

Comment: @duplode sure, but I really want a nice looking do notation (it's Shake file, I want it to look very imperative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is an XY problem, I'll answer both the question you asked, and the question you probably wanted to ask:

> `WrappedArrow` is an instance of `Applicative`, but can it be made a `Monad` (probably if the arrow is `ArrowApply`)?

Yes it can, but you'll need more constraints. In fact, I think there are several ways to do this. For example, you could take the approach suggested by @user2407038:

```
class Arrow a => ArrowSwap a where
  swap :: a b (a c d) -> a c (a b d)

instance (ArrowApply a, ArrowSwap a) => Monad (WrappedArrow a b) where
  return = pure
  WrapArrow m >>= f = WrapArrow $ swap (arr (unwrapArrow . f)) &&& m >>> app
```

You can get some intuition for `ArrowSwap` via its instance for `(->)`:

```
instance ArrowSwap (->) where
  swap :: (b -> (c -> d)) -> c -> b -> d
  swap = flip
```

Of course, it isn't immediately clear that this is useful...

> My initial purpose was to have a Monad instance for (wrapped) Kleisli,
>   so I could write
>
> ```
> runWithInput input $ do
>   action1
>   action2
>   action3
>   ...
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> do
>   output1 <- action1 input
>   output2 <- action2 output1
>   output3 <- action3 output2
>   ...
> ```

This is what [`RebindableSyntax`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#rebindable-syntax-and-the-implicit-prelude-import) is for:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

 import Control.Monad (>=>)

 action1 :: Monad m => T1 -> m T2
 action2 :: Monad m => T2 -> m T3
 action3 :: Monad m => T3 -> m T4

 action4 :: Monad m => T1 -> m T4
 action4 = let (>>) = (>=>) in do
   action1
   action2
   action3
```

Comment: Given the analogous functions in *base*, `ArrowFlip` and `flip` would arguably be more transparent names.

Comment: @duplode I completely agree! I initially had it written as such, but that meant that for my sample instance I'd have to import the Prelude qualified, and then use the qualified `flip`. I thought that might not be worth it. :)

Comment: That would be annoying indeed. In fact, I had momentarily forgotten that, at some point while playing with this question, I had in fact defined a `fleep` function in GHCi :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of `RebindableSyntax`! It should also be useful until `ApplicativeDo` becomes smart enough to put `*>` instead of `>>`. (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12666)

Answer (score 1):

> `WrappedArrow` is an instance of `Applicative`, but can it be made a `Monad` (probably if the arrow is `ArrowApply`)?

I will put `WrappedArrow` aside for a moment and consider the subtly different question "Can we successfully implement `instance ArrowApply y => Monad (y r)`?". The answer to this question is "yes". One way of demonstrating it relies on the [`ArrowMonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowMonad) newtype chi mentions...

```
newtype ArrowMonad a b = ArrowMonad (a () b)
```

... and the following isomorphism (cf. [this cstheory.SE question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/32257/35281) and page 18 of [*Idioms are oblivious, arrows are meticulous, monads are promiscuous*](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/arrows-and-idioms/arrows-and-idioms.pdf)):

```
kleislify :: ArrowApply y => y r a -> (r -> y () a)
kleislify af = \r -> arr (const r) >>> af

unkleislify :: ArrowApply y => (r -> y () a) -> y r a
unkleislify f = arr f &&& arr (const ()) >>> app

-- unkleislify . kleislify = kleislify . unkleislify = id
```

`ArrowMonad` gives us a monad instance that we can use by `kleislify`-ing the arrows and supplying a common argument to the resulting functions (in other words, we are using the `ArrowMonad` bind through the applicative instance for functions):

```
bindY :: ArrowApply y => y r a -> (a -> y r b) -> y r b
bindY af h = unkleislify $ (\(ArrowMonad am) -> am) . (\r ->
    ArrowMonad (kleislify af r) >>= \x -> ArrowMonad (kleislify (h x) r))
```

The relevant `return` is also the `ArrowMonad` one, couched in the appropriate layers of boilerplate:

```
returnY :: ArrowApply y => a -> y r a
returnY x = unkleislify $ \r -> (\(ArrowMonad am) -> am) (return x)
```

This, however, does not answer your question. For that to happen, `bindY` and `returnY` should be consistent with the `Applicative` instance of `WrappedArrow`; that is, we should have `returnY x = arr (const x)`, and the `ap` we can write with `bindY` and `returnY` should be equivalent to `(<*>)` for `WrappedMonad`. For instance, we might try using the definitions of the relevant `ArrowMonad` instances...

```
instance Arrow a => Applicative (ArrowMonad a) where
   pure x = ArrowMonad (arr (const x))
   ArrowMonad f <*> ArrowMonad x = ArrowMonad (f &&& x >>> arr (uncurry id))

instance ArrowApply a => Monad (ArrowMonad a) where
    ArrowMonad m >>= f = ArrowMonad $
        m >>> arr (\x -> let ArrowMonad h = f x in (h, ())) >>> app
```

... to expand (and then hopefully simplify) `returnY`:

```
returnY
unkleislify $ \r -> (\(ArrowMonad am) -> am) (return x)
unkleislify $ \r -> (\(ArrowMonad am) -> am) (ArrowMonad (arr (const x)))
unkleislify $ \r -> arr (const x)
arr (\r -> arr (const x)) &&& arr (const ()) >>> app
arr (const (arr (const x))) &&& arr (const ()) >>> app
arr (\r -> (r, r)) >>> arr (const (arr (const x))) *** arr (const ()) >>> app
arr (\r -> (arr (const x), ())) >>> app
```

I have no idea whether that can be simplified to `arr (const x)` for any `ArrowApply`. Perhaps being able to flip arrows (as Alec and user2407038 suggest) would help getting rid of the `()`, but I haven't worked that out. In any case, for `Kleisli` at least we can carry on:

```
arr (\r -> (arr (const x), ())) >>> app
Kleisli (\r -> return (arr (const x), ())) >>> Kleisli (\(Kleisli f, x) -> f x)
Kleisli ((\r -> return (arr (const x), ())) >=> (\(Kleisli f, x) -> f x))
Kleisli ((\r -> return (Kleisli (return . const x), ()))
    >=> (\(Kleisli f, x) -> f x))
Kleisli (\r -> return (Kleisli (return . const x), ())
    >>= (\(Kleisli f, x) -> f x))
Kleisli (\r -> (\(Kleisli f, x) -> f x) (Kleisli (return . const x), ()))
Kleisli (\r -> (return . const x) ())
Kleisli (\r -> return x)
Kleisli (return . const x)
arr (const x)
```

I haven't attempted doing the same with `bindY`, but my uninformed guess is that a similar scenario would result.

Comment: I was doing something similar last night and I thought about adding a `Monoid` or `Default` constraint (to deal with the problem of `()`). But I am not sure that would give something satisfying the `Monad` laws. My intuition says not... Nice explanation!